# Nuxt.js | Cannot read property of returned object of computed method

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I use computed method to dynamically assign varialbes and load my page. I can display the whole object. However I cant display a single property. Error message says:

> Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

thats my "pages" component's code ("_id.vue"):

```
> <template>
>     <div class="container">
>       <h1>{{ post }}</h1>
>     </div> </template> <script>   import axios from 'axios';
>     export default {
>         data() {
>           return{
>             id: this.$route.params.id,
>             posts:[]
>           }
>         },
>       computed: {
>           post(){
>             console.log(this.id);
>             return this.posts.find(post => post.id == this.id)
>         }
>       },
>     async created() {
>         await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=3")
>               .then(res => this.posts = res.data)
>               .catch(err => alert(err));
>       }
>     } </script>
> 
> <style scoped>
> 
> </style>
```

As it is know I to would display the whole object on the page. If i change the the h1 tag for:

```
<h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
```

It displays error message mentioned above.
Can you please help me solve this.

Comment: why are you using `async` if you treat the `created` as normal code?... instead of axios, I'm using `fetch` but [see the result here](https://codepen.io/balexandre/pen/yLNGXPr)

Answer (score 2):

try with conditional render:

```
<h1 v-if="post.title">{{ post.title }}</h1>
```

Comment: v-if="post" solves the problem. However, Is such a solution acceptable in professional development?

Comment: @JarekBernatowicz it's the best way and it's acceptable

Comment: It's very weird for me why it wasnt mentioned at vueschool.io

Comment: sure, but you can also do conditional rendering when `post.title` doesn't exists with `v-else` directive showing something as `post not found`. I mean u can use some `suspense` spinner while is loading, other for your `post` and when have not results